# How to I find out when my WCF server has exited (and closed it TCP connection)

Tags: .net, wcf, tcp, nettcpbinding

I am using the nettcpbinding binding (with reliably messaging at present).

When the server does a **serviceHost.Close()**, the TCP connection should be cleanly closed and therefore the client side should be told.   **How do I hook this event with WCF?**  (Note this is not the same as the TCP connection being closed by a network problem, when reliably messaging may be able to recreate the connection)

If the server calls serviceHost.Abort() , then the client will never be able to send it another message, so I would expect some event to be raised after all the retry timeouts.

(The *IChannel.Faulted* and *IChannel.Closing* events do not get fired on the client side)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that WCF does not expose a lot of what TCP can do, as it thinks that HTTP is the centre of the world.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but an option wpuld be to configure your service as a [duplex service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) and send a termination notification to clients before closing the service host.

Comment: Given that raw "socket" programming tells me when the server side of the TCP connection has been closed, I was hoping for the same from WCF.